# for deletion of a node at any index ,i'm not able to understand last line of code " temp.next = t;"

Tags: java, reference, singly-linked-list

`static class Node {
        E data;
        Node next;

```
    public Node(E data) {
        this.data = data;
        next = null;
    }
}
        public void deleteAtIndex(int index){     
        Node temp = head;
        for (int i = 1; i < index-1 ; i++) {
            temp=temp.next;
        }
        Node t = temp.next.next;
        temp.next = t;
       }`
```

whats the need of writing that code in java ,because it was mentioned we use " temp.next = t;" to "Unlink the deleted node from list" .if if remove last line ,code is not giving required output.

Comment: Please update your quesion's summary to be a question. You can find guidelines here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  
Also please format code snippet and include 1st line into code section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me give you an **example** -

Consider 5->6->10->15.
Let's say you want to remove 10.

Logically you want to find 6 and make it point to 15.

**First step** to do so will require you to to get the node that points to your object (The one we want to remove)

```
 for (int i = 1; i < index-1 ; i++) {
            temp=temp.next;
 }
```

In this for loop we simply locate the node which points to the object we want to remove.

---

```
    Node t = temp.next.next;   //15
    temp.next = t; // Point 6 to 15
```

We set the next node of "6" to be the next node of the object we want to remove.
Why?
Because we want it to be:
5->6->15

Your **t** param holds the node with the value of "15".

**Temp** is "6".

**Temp.next** before the change pointed to 10. After the change it will point to 15.

Comment: i just changed my "next" variable to variable "t". kindly do edit if required for that variable change.waiting for any edit by your side

Answer (score 0):

With `temp.next = next` you are updating the reference to the next node having deleted the old one. You can also see that in the `LinkedList` implementation: [#unlink(Node)](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java#L207)